# Django how to get input value by it's ID (not input name)

Tags: python, django, get, request

I have an input like

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input value="0" type="number" class="form-control summand" id="id_name" name="another_name">
 </div>
```

I know that if I use request.GET.get('another_name') I will get the value of the input, but how can I get the value of the input using its id, and not the name.

Is there really no such way to get the value of input by id? Following code doesn't work.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    value = request.GET.get('id_name')
```

Comment: Django cannot know the id of the input as the browser will not send that information by default. You would have to write some javascript to hook into the form submit and add that manually. But the real question is: why do you want that? I am sure there is a better way to achieve the underlying goal.

Comment: You cannot do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IT IS NOT POSSIBLE!**

**id** is a browser specific element. Only the **name** & **value** pair is sent to the server by default when submitting the HTML forms.

You can define a JavaScript function or event listener to convert id/value to name/value on form submit.